# PHP login function not working when I enable sha1

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, sha1

I have a PHP page that registers and logs in users. When I enable sha1, the user gets created and the encrypted password is stored in the DB, but they cannot log in. When I comment out the line to encrypt in both the user creation section as well as the login section, everthing works. Here is my code to create the user:

```
function add_member($nick_name, $email_address, $password) {
    global $db;
    $password = sha1($password);
    $query = "INSERT INTO members
                  (nick_name, email_address, password)
              VALUES
                  ('$nick_name', :email_address, :password)";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':email_address', $email_address);
    $statement->bindValue(':password', $password);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->closeCursor();
}
```

Here is my code to validate the user:

```
function is_valid_member($email_address, $password) {
    global $db;
    $password = sha1($password);
    $query = "SELECT member_ID 
              FROM members
              WHERE email_address = :email_address AND password = :password";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':email_address', $email_address);
    $statement->bindValue(':password', $password);
    $statement->execute();
        $valid = ($statement->rowCount() == 1);
    $statement->closeCursor();
    return $valid;
}
```

Again, when I comment out the "$password = sha1($password);" in both sections, everything works but the password is clear text.

Thanks!

Comment: Are the password cases different?

Comment: I am trying "test" "test" all lower case. Here is an update: When I change $password = sha1($password) to $password = MD5($password), that works perfectly.

Comment: That's interesting. What happens if you dump the `sha1()`'d values before you use them in your query? Are they different?

Comment: Did the user you are adding already exist and you just do not realize it do to the lack of errors?

Comment: just out of curiosity ¿what long is your password column?

Comment: @rkmax, my datatype column was only 32 long. That was my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to debug like this, echo your $password = sha1($password); and check your database entry, might be your datatype length truncated some text in stored password

Comment: That was my problem. My datatype length was not long enough for sha1. That is why MD5 was working and sha1 was not. Thank you!